# Use of DSL? Worth Reading It?

Tags: dsl

What Is the exact use of DSL? Is it worth time spending on reading DSL's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I am assuming that this is about DSLs where a DSL is a domain specific language.
The primary purpose of a DSL is to achieve a higher productivity rate by factoring in assumptions about the "domain" of use.
This is similar to the "high level vs. low level" debate in that some people go to DSL's first and then look for APIs in a general purpose language, whereas others go to APIs first and might not even consider using a DSL.

Comment: check out this about using DSL http://www.lowcoupling.com/dslenginering